# JPA multiple queries instead of one

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class MyCloudAccount implements Serializable {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ServerInstance> servers = new HashSet<ServerInstance>();

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVER_INSTANCE")
public class ServerInstance implements Serializable {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID")
    private MyCloudAccount account;

    ...
}
```

I am getting all accounts by this code:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("SELECT e FROM ");
sql.append(persistentClass.getName());
sql.append(" e");
return entityManager.createQuery(sql.toString()).getResultList();
```

And this produces one query for the account and N queries for the servers instead of one with outer join. How to force JPA to make the query in optimal way?

Comment: Does `return entityManager.createQuery("FROM " + persistentClass.getName() + " e").list();` result in the same behaviour?

Comment: Yes the same behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I find it more convenient to use Java Persistence Query Language

you can do:

```
@NamedQueries{
    @NamedQuery(name="myQuery" query="SELECT a FROM MyCloudAccount JOIN FETCH a.servers")
}
public class MyCloudAccount{
    ...
}
```

then you can do

```
TypedQuery<MyCloudAccount> query = em.createNamedQuery("MyCloudAccount.myQuery", MyCloudAccount.class);
List<MyCloudAccount> results = query.getResultList();
```

**EDIT**
You are actually already using JPQL. The key thing to your problem is using the `JOIN FECTH` command.

Comment: Actually, the OP is using JPQL, they just named the local `sql` instead of `jpql`

Comment: @BradCupit yes indeed. I should probably say that he should use use NamedQueries

Comment: But the problem is that I have generic DAO class that handles queries like findAll(), findById, etc. I don't want to write seperate versions of the findAll() metod for all entities (or named queries).

Comment: @user1557654 OK then just add the `JOIN FETCH e.servers` command and it will fetch what you need

Comment: The JOIN FETCH works, but this is strange for me that other entities are fetch automatically without doing it this way.

Comment: @user1557654 it depends of the value of the `fetch` attribute in your `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` relationship. If it's `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` then you need the `JOIN FETCH`, if it's `fetch = FetchType.FETCH` you don't.

Comment: @phoenix7360 there is no such enum FetchType.FETCH. There is FetchType.EAGER.

Comment: @user1557654 yeah sorry it was a typo. You got my point though.